# Actionscript freehand drawing class does not working

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing

I am trying to write a simple as3 drawing class, but it does not working. Not even the events fire. What could be the problem?

Usage:

```
var drawingBoard:Drawing = new Drawing();
drawingBoard.x = 0;
drawingBoard.y = 0;
drawingBoard.width = 200;
drawingBoard.height = 100;

addChild(drawingBoard);
```

Class:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Drawing extends Sprite {
        private var prevX:Number = 0;
        private var prevY:Number = 0;
        private var board:Shape = new Shape();

        public function Drawing() {
            trace("Drawing initialized.");

            addChild(board);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDrawing);
        }

        private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Start drawing.");

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,handleDrawing);
        }

        private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Stop drawing.");

            prevX = 0;
            prevY = 0;
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,handleDrawing,false);
        }

        private function handleDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Handling drawing.");

            if (prevX == 0 || prevY == 0) {
                prevX = event.localX;
                prevY = event.localY;
            } else {
                board.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000000, 1);
                board.graphics.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
                board.graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);
                prevX = event.localX;
                prevY = event.localY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When your Drawing sprite begins it registers for some events, and becaise there is NO CONTENT yet, you can't receive any events, you should waith for added to stage event then add those events onto stage, or you could add canvas background to this sprite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all setting the `width/height` of an empty sprite doesn't do anything. If you wan't to have an empty sprite with the dimensions 200/100 you need to draw something into it.

I modified your class so that it starts working after you add it to the stage:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Drawing extends Sprite {
        private var prevX:Number = 0;
        private var prevY:Number = 0;
        private var board:Shape = new Shape();

        public function Drawing() {
            trace("Drawing initialized.");

            addChild(board);
            //clear board to white
            board.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff,1);
            board.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,100);
            board.graphics.endFill();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDrawing);
        }

        private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Start drawing.");

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,handleDrawing);
        }

        private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Stop drawing.");

            prevX = 0;
            prevY = 0;
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,handleDrawing,false);
        }

        private function handleDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Handling drawing.");

            if (prevX == 0 || prevY == 0) {
                prevX = event.localX;
                prevY = event.localY;
            } else {
                board.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000000, 1);
                board.graphics.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
                board.graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);
                prevX = event.localX;
                prevY = event.localY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to **Mr. Barış Uşaklı**'s answer, I modified the class, so it is completely functional.

Also, I modified the event handling to make the performance better, because adding new event listeners and removing them was really slow.

**Initialization:**

```
var drawingBoard:Drawing = new Drawing(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
addChild(drawingBoard);
```

**Clearing:**

```
drawingBoard.clearDrawing();
```

**Modifying color and pencil width:**

```
drawingBoard.drawingColor = 0x123456;
drawingBoard.drawindWidth = 16;
```

**Class:**

```
package {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Drawing extends Sprite {
        private var prevX:Number = 0;
        private var prevY:Number = 0;
        private var board:Shape = new Shape();
        private var isDrawing:Boolean = false;

        public var drawingColor:uint = 0x6666aa;
        public var drawingWidth:int = 2;

        public function Drawing(width:int, height:int) {
            trace("Drawing initialized.");

            addChild(board);

            board.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0); // I like transparent things
            board.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
            board.graphics.endFill();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDrawing);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleDrawing);
        }

        public function clearDrawing():void {
            board.graphics.clear();
        }

        private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Start drawing.");
            isDrawing = true;
        }

        private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace("Stop drawing.");

            prevX = 0;
            prevY = 0;
            isDrawing = false;
        }

        private function handleDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (isDrawing == true){
                trace("Handling drawing at " + event.localX + " x " + event.localY);

                if (prevX != 0 && prevY != 0) {
                    board.graphics.lineStyle(drawingWidth, drawingColor, 1);
                    board.graphics.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
                    board.graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);
                }

                prevX = event.localX;
                prevY = event.localY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```